# Need advice how to decouple logging functionality from data processing in Python

Tags: python, logging, aop

In my project, I have a set of classes that do some job by calling external commands, and return their results.
Let's call them "reports".

I want to add logging to these reports, however, a concrete logger object will be defined at runtime rather than
at the time when classes are defined.

So, for now I see two variants how to implement logging:

I. At runtime, instantiate some `ReportLogger` class instance, that can monkey-patch all given report instances with logging functionality using given concrete logger.

Pros:

- It is possible to apply logging to any child report class I really need, and not touch other classes.

Cons:

- Magic! Monkey-patching is not explicit way to do things.
- Logging is actually applied at runtime, so it's less clear to understand that there is some logging when looking to report classes code.

II. Singleton `ReportLogger` class, that wraps all reports at creation time via decorators, but accepts concrete logger at runtime.

Pros:

- Explicit and clean way to mark that these reports require logging (as well as apply it actually).

Cons:

- It's harder to deal with child classes that inherit from basic `Report` class. If, for example, in base `Report` class, some method like `collect_data()` is decorated with `@log_collect_data`, then for child classes logging will be tightly coupled with `collect_data()`. Or, maybe, I have to split actual code from `collect_data()` to, say, `_collect_data()` to modify it in child classes, call `_collect_data()` from `collect_data()`, and then wrap `collect_data()` with `@log_collect_data`.

I like second method, but I want better way to deal with child classes rather than using _collect_data(). Any advices are welcome!

Comment: I actually made a rudimentary version of your first option. See here [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/t19huqi4).

Comment: For your second option, can't you just wrap them at class instantiation, rather than at definition? Kind of like a builtin monkeypatch.

Comment: The standard logging module allows sub-loggers that can all have their own log levels and filters and output handlers, and everything can be done at runtime. Is there some reason it's inappropriate for you?